# Accidentally removed root folder in ubuntu.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, root

I accidentally removed root folder in ubuntu instance on ec2. Is it okay if i recreate the root folder manually. Are there any further implications because of this?

Comment: By "root folder," I assume you mean `/root`?  (If you had deleted the root filesystem, `/` the system would be unusable.)  Yes, you should be able to recreate manually.  The only likely issue would be if you ssh into the instance as root using keys, as the public keys in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` would need to be recreated.